# Prove $(\mathbf{E}|Y^2-v|)^2 \leq 4 v(v-(\mathbf{E} Y)^2)$ for r.v. $Y\ge 0$

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

The problem comes from Dembo's lecture note Exercise 1.3.21.

[http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eadembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf)

Let $Y \geq 0$ and $v = \mathbf{E}[Y^2] < \infty $.
Show that $\left(\mathbf{E}\left|Y^2-v\right|\right)^2 \leq 4 v\left(v-(\mathbf{E} Y)^2\right)$.

Any hint is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An easier bound is $$|Y^2-v|\leq Y^2+v \implies E[|Y^2-v|]\leq 2v \implies E[|Y^2-v|]^2\leq 4v^2$$ which has a similar (but looser) form.

Comment: Oh I see: The tighter inequality is indeed true and a hint is $(Y^2-v) = (Y-\sqrt{v})(Y+\sqrt{v})$.

Comment: Thanks! That is quite helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a common trick.

Using AM-GM, we have
$$|Y^2 - v| \le \frac{|Y - \sqrt v|^2}{2q} + \frac{q}2\, |Y + \sqrt v|^2, \quad \forall q > 0.$$

Denote $a = \mathbb{E} Y$. We have
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E} |Y^2 - v| &\le \mathbb{E}\left[
 \left(\frac{1}{2q} + \frac{q}{2}\right) Y^2 + \left(q\sqrt v - \frac{\sqrt v}{q}\right)Y + \frac{v}{2q} + \frac12 qv\right]\\
 &= \left(\frac{1}{2q} + \frac{q}{2}\right) v + \left(q\sqrt v - \frac{\sqrt v}{q}\right)a + \frac{v}{2q} + \frac12 qv\\
 &= (v + a\sqrt v)q + \frac{v - a\sqrt v}{q}, \quad \forall q > 0.
\end{align*}

Letting $q = \sqrt{\frac{v - a\sqrt v}{v + a\sqrt v}} > 0$, we have
$$\mathbb{E} |Y^2 - v| \le 2\sqrt{(v + a\sqrt v)(v - a\sqrt v)} = 2\sqrt{v(v - a^2)}.$$
(*Note*: The trivial case $v - a\sqrt v = 0$ is easily verified.)

We are done.